# DraftJs : Custom toolbar button to add a specific html element to editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm tring to create a customized Rich text editor.

How can I add a custom toolbar button with a custom function behind it to the draftjs + react-draft-wysiwyg editor?

[image]

When user click on the custom button,  a popup should appear in the editor where the text cursor is located and the popup contains a certain list.

[image]

When the user clicks on one of the list items, it should be added to the editor as a particular node.

[image]

I have tried with many text editors to implement this functionality. But I couldn't.
Even this small trying deosn't work as expected

```
sendTextToEditor = (text) => {
    const sampleMarkup =
      "<div>Bold text</b>, <i>Italic text</i><br/ ></div>" +
      '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Example link</a>';

    const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
    const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
      blocksFromHTML.entityMap
    );

    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state)
    });

    this.focusEditor();
  };
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-rich-text-editor-7xw7qp